# Is there a way to log asset load errors on non-async assets when using a CSP with nonces for scripts?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Because enabling use of nonces in CSP disables event handlers, it's not possible to add an `onerror` property to script tags to handle/report asset load issues.

Is there a recommended way to handle this? Particularly for script tags which are not loaded async.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically load an external script, you can hang CSP-safe event listeners:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"
document.head.append(script);

script.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    // handle onerror event here
    });
```

Comment: This will load the script after the rest of the head has executed. I'm looking for an approach that works when you want to load the script immediately, in order, as it would if you just had a script tag.

Comment: To keep such behaviour you can use `'unsafe-hashes'` token, but it's not support by Safari.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a separate service that only purpose to monitor, handle, and report/display errors.